# Paste x flipped pose does not change

Tags: armature, mirror, pose-mode

I'm having issues where the pose I want to mirror does zero to bare minimal change, as in the arms may move slightly but nothing is mirrored it stays the same. My old pose was scrapped and remade simply because when I use the x paste pose mirror it deforms everything. I recreated a new armature with proper naming conventions (.L and .R) Everything seems to be in order however the pose does not mirror or move at all. Is this a roll problem? Or something else?

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I think i uploaded the file. I think?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5713" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5713/)

Comment: @moonboots is this correct? I'm pretty new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some name problems, like "Leg Control.R.", you must delete the final dot ("."), otherwise it won't copy paste "Leg Control.L". Same thing for "Lower Arm IK.R.", "Leg Pole Target.R.001" and maybe some other ones...

Comment: omg... i cant believe it was a naming issue.It works fine now. I was reading other forums and they said it could be roll problem. At what point would it be a roll problem?

Comment: maybe they are referring to the IK pole angle? I'm not sure what they mean...